# Unable to send emails in rails in elasticbeanstalk due to ssl error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mailgun

I have deployed my rails application in Elasticbeanstalk instance. When I try to send emails using mailgun (or any other service) I am getting this error:

> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol

Here is my smtp settings:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.mailgun.org'
  port: '587',   #TLS port
  domain: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_domain_name,
  user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
  password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password,
  authentication: :login
}
```